# Why does my nixos installation have two paths to 'nixpkgs'?

Tags: nixos, nixpkgs

Searching my system for `nixpkgs` yields the following.

```
$ find / -name nixpkgs 2>/dev/null
/nix/store/a4080yzy7vm3c4cwj35kazqi79asi12f-nixos-17.03.1506.b6f05ca54d/nixos/nixpkgs
/nix/store/sgk7sxgqxrv2axkxjwc3y15apcqbrv1z-nixos-17.03.1482.1b57bf274a/nixos/nixpkgs
```

Why are there two paths to `nixpkgs`?

Does this mean there is something wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's perfectly fine and not a cause for concern. An example of when this may occur is updating your channel in which case you will end up with two (or potentially more) copies of nixpkgs. Even if you rebuild your system based on the updated channel an older generation of the system may still refer to the old version.
In more general case - regardless of whether it may be referred to by something Nix won't remove the old version unless garbage collection is performed.